# Linear Independence of Vectors in C

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

Problem:

> "Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ are vectors in $C^{3}$. Is the assertion:
>
> > $v_1$, $v_2$ is linearly independent over $C$
>
> grammatically correct? Explain."

Confusion:  Technically $C^3$ is over $C$, however I am not sure if it is grammatically correct with this phrasing. Would the statement

> $v_1$, $v_2$ is linearly independent in $C^3$

makes more sense?

Comment: Honestly both are legitimate if you interpret them the right way. =/ But it is probably "more" correct to say that $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Comment: If both are considered legitimate, then I think the point trying to be made is that it should be $v_1$, $v_2$ _are_ linearly independent over $C$. Instead of thinking of it as a single object, there are two separate vectors that are linearly dependent. That may be the "grammatical" error.

Comment: Perhaps so. It's a bit of an ambiguous question.